# To Display a fragment over same activity onitemclick of a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to display a fragment over the same activity. How can I do that? are there method or example realted to it? kindly suggest.

Comment: simply, add fragment and then for more fragment replace fragment within that activity

Comment: okay i'll try that,is it possible to display the fragment as message box and the background of the activity to be transparent?

Answer (score 0):

I think dialog fragment concept is used for your scenario..[click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, we have to creat a fragment and by using intent have to pass the values to that fragment. And the fragment will be displayed on the activity Screen.